# Neo4j Rails - How to filter or query based on date range/number range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

This is for Neo4jrb.

I want to set up filters on my columns. I can search for an exact date/value, but I want to know how I can find all dates/values in a range. I'm filtering on multiple columns, so ideally I would like to stick to a hash

This works for a single value

```
@users = User.all
@users.where({created_at: some_date.to_i, age: some_value})
```

This works for a range:

```
@users.as(:u).where("u.created_at >= {start_date} and u.created_at <= {end_date}")
.params(start_date: date1.to_i, end_date: date2.to_i)
```

My issue is that the filtering is dynamic and on many columns, sometimes there will be a range, sometimes now. I would like to just dynamically set a hash and just feed it to `where`

```
@users.where(filter_conditions)
```

How can I do this with Neo4j?

Comment: How do you store date information in the database?

Comment: @MicTech As a DateTime

Comment: I'm not sure how Neo4jrd store DateTime value in the Neo4j. But Neo4j doesn't support DateTime by itself and you need to transform DateTime to different format. Usually it should be an integer and DateTime should be represent as UnixTime.

Comment: @MicTech Yes, I believe it is stored as a unixtime int

Answer (score -1):

Let's suppose you specify an array of date property keys and their desired ranges:

```
[{key: "created_at", start: 123, end: 234},{key: "modified_at", start: 333, end: 333}]
```

In the above example, the `created_at` property has the range `[123...234]`, and the `modified_at` property has the range `[333...333]` -- which is just a non-range test masquerading as a range test.

With the following pseudo code, you should be able to apply all the date comparisons specified by a parameter:

```
@users.as(:u).where("ALL(x IN {data} WHERE u[x.key] >= x.start AND u[x.key] <= x.end)")
.params(data: ... an array like the one above ...)
```

Comment: This is almost identical to the solution in my question that I don't want. I would like to be able to achieve this via a ```where(hash)``` so that I can dynamically filter.

Comment: What I am proposing is a way for you to dynamically filter. Parameters are used to dynamically modify a static query, and in a performant way.